# I compare two identical sentences with RIBES NLTK and get an error. Why?

Tags: python, nltk, metrics, machine-translation

I’m trying to use RIBES score from NLTK for quality evaluation of the machine translation. I wanted to check this code with two identical sentences. But when I’m running my code I get errors.

My code:

```
from nltk.translate.ribes_score import sentence_ribes

hyp1 = ['It', 'is', 'a', 'guide', 'to', 'action', 'which', 'ensures', 'that', 'the', 'military', 'always', 'obeys', 'the', 'commands', 'of', 'the', 'party']

ref1a = ['It', 'is', 'a', 'guide', 'to', 'action', 'which', 'ensures', 'that', 'the', 'military', 'always', 'obeys', 'the', 'commands', 'of', 'the', 'party']

ribes_score = sentence_ribes(ref1a, hyp1)

print(ribes_score)
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:/Users/anastasia.emelyanova/PycharmProjects/Metrics_NLTK/ribes_test.py", line 4, in <module>

    ribes_score = sentence_ribes(ref1a, hyp1)

  File "D:\Users\anastasia.emelyanova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\translate\ribes_score.py", line 55, in sentence_ribes

    nkt = kendall_tau(worder)

  File "D:\Users\anastasia.emelyanova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\translate\ribes_score.py", line 290, in kendall_tau

    tau = 2 * num_increasing_pairs / num_possible_pairs - 1

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why I’m getting these errors? Am I mistaken? I just took two identical sentences and there shouldn’t be division by zero, because numbers of possible pairs should be more than 1. Two identical sentences should get a score 1.0. I'm coding on Python 3, Windows 7, in PyCharm. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting to a division by zero on this line:

```
tau = 2 * num_increasing_pairs / num_possible_pairs - 1
```

This is because `num_possible_pairs` is 0 when `len(worder)` is 1. All of this is because you're calling `sentence_ribes` with two lists, when the first parameter should be a list of lists (a list of sentences where each sentence is a list of words).

Try calling it like this instead:

```
ribes_score = sentence_ribes([ref1a], hyp1)
```